Link is changing but previous component only loading in firefox ( Angular Application)
In my application based upon the path redirecting to the specific components but it's when I am clicking one link it's redirecting correctly after that if am clicking another link previous component only loading .
Issue happening only in firefox
{
path : "web/:orgname/address",
component: addressComponent
},

{
path : "web/:orgname/library",
component: libraryComponent
}

In url showing address but loading library component
